# React useContext, useRedux child component does not update

Tags: reactjs, reducers, react-hooks, rerender

React application using hooks
i am using React Hooks `useContext`, and `useReducer` to mimic Redux
However, when `Context.Provider` value (counter) is updated the child components are not updated. Why does the child component not rerender?

**Store.js**

```
import React, {  useReducer } from 'react';
import reducer from '../State/Reducer';
let initialState = {
  count: 99  
};

export const StoreContext = React.createContext(initialState, () => {});

function Store({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const val = { state, dispatch };
  return <StoreContext.Provider value={val}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
}

export default Store;
```

---

**Counter.js**

```
import React, {  useContext} from 'react';
import {inc} from '../State/Actions';
import { StoreContext } from './Store';


const Counter = () => {
  const {state,dispatch} = useContext(StoreContext)
  const {count}=state;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>count: {count}</h1>      
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {      
          dispatch(inc());          
        }}
      >
        Inc
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Counter;
```

I have the sample code in CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kyrlouca/react-hooks-counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed a second argument to `ReactContext` as function which returns nothing hence you see a broken experience.

The second argument to `createContext` is a function `calculateChangedBits` which is expected to return a number and is not specified in documentation perhaps because its not expected to be overwritten

Creating context like

```
export const StoreContext = React.createContext(initialState);
```

works

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j35xkmj509)

> P.S. You can check how `calculateChangedBits` being used in `ReactContext` [**here**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8bcc88f2e7a7dc3e950bfcca1d3c6bbd251c4b20/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberNewContext.js) and [**here**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/961eb65b4ba5de6bbfb6b8a075a924c284541177/packages/react/src/ReactContext.js)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem indeed. I tried to use the same signature for the object passed to Provider